# Adding words to the webkitSpeechRecognition() for speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition, google-speech-api

I want to add words to the `webkitSpeechRecognition()` word library so that when I say these new words, they can be detected and written down. ([Here](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/9a0075d25326/speechapi.html) is the link to the Web Speech API that I am using). I tried looking how to do this, but I can't find a way. If there is a way to do this, how can I?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in the current implementation.

If you want to recognize a limited amount of non-standard words you can use external solutions like:

http://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this